# how can I move a UIScrollView with a swipe gesture as a trigger

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

is there a way to use the swipe gesture to control the amount of scrolling in a UIScrollView.

What I'm trying to do is to use the scroll view as a stage for my entire UI. And I want to use the swipe action to trigger moving my 'stage' from one side to the other with a fixed distance. You can think of it a some sort of window that only sees a part of the entire UI at a time and I want to move the visible area on user interaction.

The problem that I'm having is that the little test I did doesn't even start properly and quits with a black screen and no specific error message.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks 
tim

Comment: Does it need to be a UIScrollView? Have you tried working with pagingEnabled property? Have you checked out UIPageUViewController?

Comment: can you explain why the basic UIScrollView behavior is not ok for you? furthermore, I understand you better show some code so we can help out with making it work in the first place... this has nothing to do with the gesture recognizer and your app would keep not working if we just advice about the gesture recognizer, I fear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `pagingEnabled` property of your `UIScrollView` instance to `YES`.

Starting from iOS 5, you can also implement in your `UIScrollViewDelegate` implementation the following method: `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` (make sure `pagingEnabled` is set to `NO` in this case, otherwise the method won't be called).